# Is the proof below able to verify both sequence yield the same value of $p_n$ when n tend to infinity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, numerical-methods

Consider the sequence below

$2.5p_0v_0-p_0(\frac{h}{n})=2.5p_1(v_0+\frac{h}{n})$

$2.5p_1(v_0+\frac{h}{n})-p_1(\frac{h}{n})=2.5p_2(v_0+2\frac{h}{n})$

.

.

.

$2.5p_{n-1}(v_0+(n-1)\frac{h}{n})-p_{n-1}(\frac{h}{n})=2.5p_n(v_0+h)$

and second sequence

$p_0v_0^{1.08687}-0.31313p_0v_0^{0.08687}(\frac{h}{n})=p_1(v_0+\frac{h}{n})^{1.08687}$

$p_1(v_0+\frac{h}{n})^{1.08687}-0.31313p_{1}(v_0+\frac{h}{n})^{0.08687}(\frac{h}{n})=p_2(v_0+2\frac{h}{n})^{1.08687}$

.

.

.

$p_{n-1}(v_0+(n-1)\frac{h}{n})^{1.08687}-0.31313p_{n-1}(v_0+(n-1)\frac{h}{n})^{0.08687}(\frac{h}{n})=p_n(v_0+h)^{1.08687}$

Does this make sense to say both sequence is the numerical integration for DE $\frac{dp}{dv}=-1.4\frac{p}{v}$,when n tend to infinity where the exact solution of this DE is $p_0v_0^{1.4}$=constant consider $p(v_0)=p_0$ which is actually the adiabatic process in diatomic gas.

I treat the first sequence $E=u(p,v)=2.5pv$ and $\frac{dE}{dv}=g(p,v)=-p$

using

$u_p\frac{dp}{dv}+u_v$

$2.5v\frac{dp}{dv}+2.5p$=$-p$

$\frac{dp}{dv}=-1.4\frac{p}{v}$

and second sequence $E=u_1(p,v)=pv^{1.08687}$, $\frac{dE}{dv}=g_1(p,v)$=$-0.31313p$

did the same as above which yield $\frac{dp}{dv}=-1.4\frac{p}{v}$

Attached also printscreen of python of the sequence but I afraid practically is not possible to show exactly the same so theoretically if n tend to infinity, is $p_n$ the same for both sequence? Consider $p(v_0)=p_0$ and h is constant.

first sequence

[image]

second sequence[image]

Where the algorithm calculate $p_n=p(v)=p(51)$ using $n=50000,h=50,p(1)=1$ while the exact solution using $pv^{1.4}$=constant is $p(51)=\frac{1}{51^{1.4}}=0.00406819$

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by focusing on first order methods? Why do you need numerical methods when you know the exact solution?

Comment: Please use a text copy of your code and results instead of an image copy. It will be more compact, smaller in bandwidth, and copyable for verification and experimentation. Use the `code markup` for an appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the explicit Euler method is convergent with order 1. As the differential equations are equivalent and all are regular for $v\in[1,51]$ with smooth right sides, the method is applicable, converges for these ODE, and in the limit will converge to equivalent solutions.

If $q=pv^a$, then $\frac{dq}{dv}=v^a\frac{dp}{dv}+apv^{a-1}=(-1.4+a)pv^{a-1}=(-1.4+a)\frac{q}v$ and the Euler method for this equation reads
$$
q_{n+1}=q_n+\Delta v\,(-1.4+a)\frac{q_n}{v_n}\iff p_{n+1}v_{n+1}^a=p_{n}v_{n}^a-\Delta v\,(1.4-a)p_{n}v_{n}^{a-1}
$$
In your case, $a=1$ or $a=1.08687$ (with $1.4-a=0.31313$).